# How can I link text added with pseudo :before classes inside a list

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have a list with every item linked. Some groups of items will have an added text using :before. The text won't be linked but it is executing onmouseover states. Also, a mouseover on the :before added text won't activate the hover in the link. Any ideas?

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grundum/1tj6hb4k/10/

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li onmouseover="changeImage()"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li onmouseover="changeImage()"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li onmouseover="changeImage()"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li onmouseover="changeImage()"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li onmouseover="changeImage()"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li onmouseover="changeImage()"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li onmouseover="changeImage()"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li onmouseover="changeImage()"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li onmouseover="changeImage()"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
  <li onmouseover="changeImage()"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
a:link {
  color:#333;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover{
  color: #0078F9;
}

li{
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}

li:hover:before {
    color: #0078F9;
}


li:nth-child(1):before, li:nth-child(2):before, li:nth-child(3):before, li:nth-child(4):before, li:nth-child(5):before{
        display:inline-block;
        content: ">>>>>";
        padding-right:7px;
}

li:nth-child(6):before, li:nth-child(7):before, li:nth-child(8):before, li:nth-child(9):before, li:nth-child(10):before{
        display:inline-block;
        content: ">>>>>>>>>>";
        padding-right:7px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you? Modify each `li:nth-child(1):before,` to be `li:nth-child(1) a:before,`

https://jsfiddle.net/evrmorr/bjom5qv8/3/